# How to create an object with given keys and values?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given three arguments ⁠— an object obj of the stolen items, the pets name and a value ⁠— return an object with that name and value in it (as key-value pairs)

```
  addName({}, "Brutus", 300) ➞ { Brutus: 300 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Read about objects first: [Working_with_Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

```js
//  addName({}, "Brutus", 300) ➞ { Brutus: 300 }

function addName(object, name, price) {
  object[name] = price;
  return object;
}

console.log(addName({}, "Brutus", 300))
```